# Change the colour of individual bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I have two dictionaries-
selected candidates and rejected candidates.
the structure is like as shown below-
selected={"name":score} #same for rejected
I want to show selected candidates in the green and rejected candidates in red.
How can I do that?

I have tried this way but it is giving me some absurd result:

```
#Husain Shaikh
#test 3 matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
selected={"Husain":92, "Asim":65,"Chirag": 74 }
rejected={"Absar":70,"premraj":57}
plt.bar(range(len(selected)),list(selected.values()),color="green")
plt.xticks(range(len(selected)),list(selected.keys()))
plt.bar(range(len(rejected)),list(rejected.values()),color="red")
plt.xticks(range(len(rejected)),list(rejected.keys()))
plt.xlabel("Candidates")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Both your bars for rejected and selected are plotted at the same x positions and so they overlap each other and that’s why you see some weird mixture. Put aloha =0.3 in bar plot command and you will see the two bars behind each other

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
selected={"Husain":92, "Asim":65,"Chirag": 74 }
rejected={"Absar":70,"premraj":57}     
selected_candidates_number = len(selected)
rejected_candidates_number = len(rejected)
plt.bar(range(selected_candidates_number ),list(selected.values()),color="green")
plt.bar(range(selected_candidates_number,selected_candidates_number +rejected_candidates_number ),list(rejected.values()),color="red")
plt.xticks(range(selected_candidates_number +rejected_candidates_number), list(selected.keys()) + list(rejected.keys()))
plt.xlabel("Candidates")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't want to plot the histogram. you can see my approach above, can you show a similar but right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I am only showing the relevant/modified part of the code

```
# Import numpy, matplotlib and data here

loc_s = np.arange(len(selected))+0.1 # Offsetting the tick-label location
loc_r = np.arange(len(rejected))-0.1 # Offsetting the tick-label location
xtick_loc = list(loc_s) + list(loc_r)
xticks = list(selected.keys())+ list(rejected.keys())

plt.bar(loc_s,list(selected.values()),color="green", width=0.2,label='Selected')
plt.bar(loc_r,list(rejected.values()),color="red", width=0.2,label='Rejected')
plt.xticks(xtick_loc, xticks, rotation=45)

# Labels and legend here
```

**Output**

[image]